# Git (on-prem) - TFS2013 - How to create and commit new project from VS2019 to TFS2013 (with Git)

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, tfs-2013

The internet is awash with how to create and commit a new project to GitHub, however, there are near-zero resources as to how to accomplish this with TFS2013/Git on-prem.

We have an old TFS2013 server currently being updated, but we are 'stuck' with this for the time being.   Since the move to VS2019, we have not found a way to commit a new project to Git (on-prem, embedded into TFS2013).

I have installed a fresh TFS2013 server with the one DefaultCollection.  I can add projects to this collection from VS2019, *as a TFS project*.  However, I cannot seem to do it with *Git*.

When I follow the commands, as if it were a remote GitHub repo, I repeatedly receive the message "The Git repository with name or identifier XXXX does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting".

How does one create and commit to Git, on-prem, from VS2019?  Command-line, or VS2019 commands would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed a fresh TFS2013 server with the one DefaultCollection. I can add projects to this collection from VS2019, as a TFS project. However, I cannot seem to do it with Git.

Maybe the reason is that you can't create a git repository in the same project than one created with TFVC source control. This possibility was only provided in tfs2015.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/team-projects?view=azure-devops

So you will have to create another project to host git repositories.

From there, you will have to create first the repository from the web interface and use it from visual studio or the command line (by adding it as a remote if your local git repository is already created).

Maybe using the command line is easier for initializing the git repository because nothing is specific to tfs2013 and I don't remember the interface and you will found a lot of documentation as long as you have the repository Uri.